# Magmi Image path not found

Tags: php, csv, magento, magento-1.9, magmi

I am uploading 1000 products to Magento 1.9 using Magmi's [Image Attributes Processor](http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php/Image_attributes_processor) and receive the following error

> SKU 3800231 - Image attributes processor v1.0.33 - path/853698004078.jpg cannot be found in images path

my file structure as follow

```
Shop/MagentoRoot/Magmi/
                /var/import/xxxxx.csv
                /media/import/xxxxxxx.jpg
```

I have tried the following as my path in my .csv

```
/xxxx.jpg
xxxx.jpg
/media/import/xxx.jpg
/shop/MagentoRoot/media/import/xxx.jpg
/home/ShareServerPath/public_html/shop/MagentoRoot/media/import/xxx.jpg
```

what is the right path? or how do i debug it to find the right path
thank you

Comment: I can't remember but I think it might be relative to the magmi root, so something like ../media/import might work.

Answer (score 1):

The path you set for the images may be right, but are maybe not reachable by Magento.

Check the path of Magento you have set in the global configuration, that is under Configure Global Parameters / Magento / Filesystem Path to magento directory. It needs to be an absolute path.

[image]

Comment: How can i import images for my multi-store, can i get csv header column values,, my csv : https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Step 1) Check for "/" in csv file path. If you have added images in "media/import/" then do not add "/" in image, small_image & thumbnail.

Step 2) Make sure Image attribute Processor is enabled and inside of it "Image search path:" filed has "media/import" value.

[image]

And make sure after uploading you have reindexed and cleared the cache from Magento admin.

Comment: How can i import images for my multi-store, can i get csv header column values,, my csv : https://snag.gy/e3kioC.jpg

Comment: please create another thread and give link I will answer there.

Comment: @ Rushabh Shah : I have reached my question limit, so can't able to post as a new question, could you pls share here.